# misunderestanding of logical operator of c language

Tags: c, mips

I have such these questions in my book that I have do it for checking my self but I don't know the correct answer and there is no any explanation.

it has two parts "a" and "b"

```
a) A = B & C[0]
b) A = A ? B : C[0]

C[0]  = 0x00001234
A = 0x00000000
B = 0x00002222
```

it want from me that

```
1)what is the result of A 
2) the MIPS instruction for each part
3)show the bit level representation of each in structure.
```

thanks

Comment: The '&' is a bitwise and, NOT a logical operator. What are the starting values of B and C? (Are they 0x1234 and 0x2222?) You can figure out A from that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a bit-wise AND. Each bit of the output is 1 if both corresponding input bits are 1:

```
0x00001234 = .... 0001 0010 0011 0100
0x00002222 = .... 0010 0010 0010 0010

AND result = .... 0000 0010 0010 0000 = 0x00000220
```

I don't know MIPS but the instruction is probably just called `and`.

`?` is the ternary operator: your example means "if A is a true boolean expression then return B else return C[0]". Generally in C false is zero and true non-zero (I'm not 100% sure if this is standardised - I don't think it was in the earlier standards, but it's common uses) so

- if A = 0x0000 then (bool)A == false and the result is C[0].
- if A = 0x0220 (carrying forward the result from part a) then (bool)A == true and the result is B.

Comment: Fine except for the last part: 0x0220 (or any other non-zero value) evaluates to TRUE in C and C-related languages.

Comment: @Paul I'd read a) and b) as separate questions so I was using the initial value of A in the question = 0x0000. But yes, if the values carry through then A is true and the result of b) is B.

Comment: @Rup: ah yes, I see the ambiguity in the question now - I suspect that (b) is supposed to follow on from (a) with a A = 0x0220, but as you say, it's not 100% clear.

Comment: Did I get it wrong? Hex to binary is easy because each hex digit (decimal 0-15) is exactly four bits, so the digits map as 0x1 = 0001, 0x2 = 0010, 0x3 = 0011 .. 0xf = 1111.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is the bit-wise AND operator in C. 
eg. 
0000 & 0001 = 0000

`?` is another way of writing `if`

```
A = A ? B : C[0]
```

says that A gets the value = (if A is true then B ELSE C[0])

Convert for Hex to Binary and do the exercise.

edit : clarify : made "AND" to -> "bit-wise AND"

Comment: for the first question I have to convert the result to hex or not?

Comment: you should if you want to perform the bitwise AND.

Comment: A=A will check the binary or the hex?

Comment: also keep in mind that something is false when it has a value 0. eg. if A is 0000 after the &, this will be false, and it will get the value C[0]

Comment: binary and hex are just different representations of the same thing

Comment: also what does it mean with bit level representation?

Answer (score 1):

the mips:

a) A = B & C[0]

$t1 = C

$t2 = B

$t3 = A

lw  $t0, 0($t1)   ;move c into temp reg

and $t3, $t0, $t2 ;perform bitwise and

b) A = A ? B : C[0]

$t1 = C

$t2 = B

$t3 = A

beq $0, $t3, 3    ;if A is 0 go 3 lines down

add $t3, $0, $t2  ;move B to A

j end             ;goto the end

lw  $t0, 0($t1)   ;load c into a temp reg

add $t3, $0, $t0  ;move temp value into a

end: